# jquery image anime

Tags: jquery, image

On a div, I'll like that the background image to move continuously from top to bottom.

Is that possible by using jQuery? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Queness](http://www.queness.com/post/2607/create-background-scrolling-effect-with-jquery) seems to be what you're after, it does vertical, horizontal and diagonal background image movement.

The attached link should have everything you need to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could go with a
$("div").animate({backgroundPosition: "100px 1000px"}, 3000);
or something similar

Comment: This was just an example and not the whole solution

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

hope this helps